# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at Object.parse (native) PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, json

I am trying to display Data in MySQL DB. But, I keep getting SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at Object.parse (native) .

My PHP file which fetch the data is

```
<?php 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"); 

include_once 'config/database.php'; 
include_once 'objects/ideas.php'; 

$database = new Database(); 
$db = $database->getConnection();

$ideas = new ideas($db);

$stmt = $ideas->readAll();
$num = $stmt->rowCount();

if($num>0){

    $data="";
    $x=1;


    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        // extract row
        // this will make $row['name'] to
        // just $name only
        extract($row);

        $data .= '{';
            $data .= '"id":"'  . $id . '",';
            $data .= '"name":"' . $name . '",';
            $data .= '"description":"' . html_entity_decode($description) . '",';
            $data .= '"SubmitedBy":"' . $SubmitedBy  . '",';
        $data .= '}'; 

        $data .= $x<$num ? ',' : ''; $x++; } 
} 

// json format output 
echo '{"records":[' . $data . ']}'; 
?>
```

My AngularJS Code,

```
 $scope.getAll = function() {
                $http.get("read_ideas.php").success(function(response) {
                    $scope.names = response.records;
                });
            }
```

And the Data in MySQL DB is just

```
id - 1
name - me
description - desc
SubmitedBy - me
created - 2016-05-19 14:13:10
modified - 2016-05-19 17:43:10
```

I am not able to figure out why it throws this error again and again.

i understand it is somehow not able to parse the data in db to JSON format. But, how can i fix it.

Comment: What does the resulting JSON look like? Have you tested it is valid? Why on earth are you generating it by bashing strings together instead of using `json_encode`?!

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ is good online tool to check your JSON structure.

Comment: Tried the  'echo json_encode($row);' still its not working.

Comment: You actually have an extra `,` at the end of your last object, `SubmitedBy` x) you have to remove it, so it should be `$data .= '"SubmitedBy":"' . $SubmitedBy  . '";`

Comment: @MiguelGuerreiro, thanks it worked.

Comment: @shubhamdeodia no problem c: Please accept my answer if I helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have an extra `,` at the end of your last object, `SubmitedBy` x) you have to remove it, so it should be

```
 $data .= '"SubmitedBy":"' . $SubmitedBy . '";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are actually adding a `,` at the last value of `SubmitedBy` replace this

```
$data .= '"SubmitedBy":"' . $SubmitedBy  . '",';
```

with this

```
$data .= '"SubmitedBy":"' . $SubmitedBy;
```

Comment: I tried, still its giving me below error

angular.min.js:117 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at Object.parse (native)